# Fedora 31 touchpad issues and Wayland?

Tags: fedora

[image]Hi folks Im a new user to Linux comining from mac.

HP envy x360 Ryzen 7, Radeon vega graphics. When it works it works well.

But the touchpad and touch screen are glitchy and for some reason I cant update.

[image]

Im completely in the dark here

and just hope someone can help

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text, you can copy and paste that into your question into a code block.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm quite new to this. I will have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up